# Non -linear congruence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, congruences

I am having a hard time solving $x^3 - 5x \equiv 340 \pmod{648}$.

I know enough about Jacobi and Legendre symbols to understand a solution using them.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Do you know about Jacobi or Legendre symbols? You need to know if $5$ is a square$\pmod{648}$.

Comment: yes, not too much, but i can understand a solution using them

Answer (score 2):

$648 =2^3 3^4.$  The usual technique would be to solve mod $2$ and then use Hensel's lemma to lift to mod $4$ and then mod $8$.  Repeat for mods $3, 9, 27, 81.$  Then use your solutions mod $8$ and $81$ with Chinese Remainder theorem to get the final answers.  There are 5 solutions mod $648.$

Comment: Thanks +1, I'd be interested to see the first part of this, at least for one of the primes.